# Calculating Exponential Moving Average using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to find out exponential moving average (12 days) for a dataframe. As given in the pandas documentation 0.19.2, I've used the function DataFrame.ewm to calcuate the exponential moving average. But it results in an error as follows AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ewm'. Below is the code I've used to calculate exponential moving average.

```
avg_gain=pd.gain.ewm(span=12,min_periods=12,adjust=False).mean()
```

On the other hand, in prior pandas documentation there is function ewma to calculate exponential moving average but this function results in undesired results.
Can't figure out the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using an older version of `pandas`.

```
import pandas
pandas.__version__
```

To upgrade, use `pip`.

```
sudo pip3 install pandas --upgrade  # UNIX
pip install pandas --upgrade  # Windows
```

If you do not have `pip` installed, you can replace `pip` with `python -m "pip"`, or `pip3` with `python3 -m "pip"`.